# Webpack 4 and sass-resources-loader

Tags: webpack, create-react-app, css-modules

I'm trying to use webpack 4 in app created with create-react-app 2.0 which uses webpack 4. 
For some reason I'm getting:

```
./src/components/Registration/_registration.scss (./node_modules/css-loader??ref--6-oneOf-5-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--6-oneOf-5-3!./src/components/Registration/_registration.scss)
  color: $testColor;
        ^
      Undefined variable: "$testColor".
      in /Users/Bartosz/Projects/penzo-web/src/components/Registration/_registration.scss (line 2, column 10)
```

This is a part of webpack which should load sass-resources-loader:

```
 {
  test: /\.scss$/,
  use: [
    'style-loader',
    'css-loader',
    'postcss-loader',
    'sass-loader',
    {
      loader: 'sass-resources-loader',
      options: {
        // Provide path to the file with resources
        resources: './src/styles/modules/_variables.scss',
      },
    },
  ],
},
```

Apart from this part all is configured by create-react-app.

Thank you for helping!

Comment: Where's the `$testColor` defined?

Comment: @ArtyomNeustroev it is defined in the ./src/styles/modules/_variables.scss (I modified the question a bit)

Comment: does not look wrong from what I can tell.. could it be that this configuration is never actually applied?

Comment: If you look `sass-resources-loader` is not part of the `require`. It should be the loader in the end. Probably the configuration is never applied. Try to remove `sass-loader` for example to check if there is an error.